# SpringSource Tool Suite problem

Tags: grails

I installed STS 2.6.1.SR1 + added groovy & grails extensions. The Grails installation is pointing to Grails1.4 (Preferences->Grails). However, I can not perform any grails-related actions, like creating a new project. After importing an existing grails project (which was created in command prompt), it even can not be compiled. An output is always the same:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/groovy/tools/RootLoader
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Exception in thread "main"
```

Have anyone faced something similar?
Alex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.4 was only released a few days ago and its structure is quite different from previous releases. STS doesn't support it yet but this is being worked on and it will soon.

Comment: Thanks, I've installed Grails 1.7, which was provided on STS Extensions page, now this problem is gone, however, another problem has occurred. Now grails can not find some of its dependencies. What could be a reason of that problem?

Comment: You'll need to provide details (should be a new question), it could be several things.

Comment: Thanx! It was ivy cash problem, after cleaning it, everything seems working fine.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1 -> Upgrade STS**

SpringSource Tool Suite 2.7.0.M2 has now been released and supports Grails 1.4.  [Release notes are here](http://www.springsource.org/node/3151)

---

**Option 2 -> Workaround.**

Full details are available on the [Spring Source Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-1729) but this workaround may help...

com.springsource.sts.grails.core.internal.model.DefaultGrailsInstall.getBootstrapClasspath doesn't look for groovy-all-x.jar in the location where Grails 1.4 keeps it.

Workaround for running Grails 1.4 apps in STS:

```
cd /opt/grails-1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/lib
ln -s org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/jars/groovy-all-1.8.0.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not an elegant solution but FWIW, with a similar issue (wanting groovy 1.8 in grails 1.3.7) I've found in practice that swapping the grails-1.3.7/lib/groovy-all-1.7.8.jar with groovy-all-1.8.4.jar works -- except you have to call the 1.8.4 jar "groovy-all-1.7.8.jar".

Worked for my app (for dev/test until newer grails is available) but of course YMMV.